# can't find method in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I've been trying to get authentication working with devise, and then omniauth, but I haven't been able to get the user session.

In my application controller, I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    protect_from_forgery



private
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
    helper_method :current_user

end
```

which I got from the updated railscast https://github.com/railscasts/241-simple-omniauth/blob/master/revised/blog-after/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

In my app, I call

```
<% if current_user %>
```

but this always errors out as `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`

why is this? is it a problem with my application controller, or maybe a session error with rails?

Comment: Try to move the `helper_method :current_user` to outside the `private` declaration. Just a shot.

Comment: thanks @KleberS., I tried that,  but it didn't help. The tutorial has it outside of private, but the source has it inside, neither is working.